# Selenium didn't see that attribute value has changed

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get number of notifications from element using Selenium, but it didn't see changes. Number of messages just a number above notification icon, like on picture:

[image]

But then I trying to process this element:

```
notify_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'data-count')))
    count_of_notify = int(notify_element.get_attribute('data-count'))
```

I recive **count_of_notify = 0**. I don't understand why.

Code of this element:

```
<a id="notify-toggle" class="toggle link">
    <span title="Уведомления" class="data-count" data-count="1" data-icon="">
    </span>
</a>
```

But `data-count` changes depanding on number of notifications.

Comment: Did you check if you are locating the right element using `class='data-count'`? Instead, can you check with the `XPath` using its parent element!!

Comment: Thank you! You were right, I consider wrong element, now I find necessary element, and it works